# Issue in file_get_contents(), it is working on the localhost but not working on the host server

Tags: php

```php
<?php 

$sUrl = 'http://125.209.77.54:8181/locationVeh/LED:18:4089/KrvpjgKAQyTJlfz05Urijw==';

$params = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST'));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);

$response = file_get_contents($sUrl, false, $ctx);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response;

echo $data['lat'];

echo $data['lng'];

?>
```

I tested on the localhost it works fine which shows 29.88288 and 71.7381 while on the host server shows empty. I tried to use `allow_url_open` to  1.

Comment: For this usage use cUrl function to do this, it's not really a reading of document it's more an request to an API. Take a look here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php

Comment: If you're using shared hosting then there's a chance the remote API is blocking the IP that you're making requests from.

Comment: Curl is not the magic solution to every networking problem, esp. if you don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: You need to gather a bare minimum diagnostics information: check return values, enable error reporting, view server logs, that kind of stuff. Applying random fixes until it starts working is not fun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Host server fopen is disabled that's why file_get_contents() function is not working on server . You can use the Curl to get the data .

To check the fopen create the phpinfo(); in test PHP and run test.php file

Thanks